# Changing to Polar Coordinates for Area between $2$ Tangent Circles

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to calculate a double integral over: $\{(x,y) | 4x \leq x^2+y^2\leq 5x\}$. 
I am trying to change to polar coordinates. So the theta would go from $0$ to $2\pi$. But I am not sure what should be the boundaries of the radius, since the two circles are tangent in $(0,0)$ and don't have the same center point. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It will work as usual with $x = r\cos \theta, y = r\sin \theta $. Thus the first inequality translates to: $4r\cos \theta \leq r^2$ or $4\cos \theta \leq r$ and the second inequality becomes: $r^2 \leq 5r\cos \theta$ or $r \leq 5\cos \theta$. Thus $I = \displaystyle \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{4\cos \theta}^{5\cos \theta} rdrd\theta$. To see the outer bounds, draw the $2$ circles yourself and you can see the bounds.

Comment: The outer bounds are incorrect—you’re in effect tracing the circles twice.

Comment: I drew the circles and can't understand why it's $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$. Doesn't that omit part of the area? http://i.imgur.com/gng5BzS.png